# react router basic example gives error Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

Tags: react-router

following react training documentation to learn basics of [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/02-rendering-a-route) but it failed on the very first example. below is my **package.json** info

```
    "dependencies": {
        "history": "^4.7.2",
        "react": "^0.14.7",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
        "react-router": "^2.0.0"
    },
```

and this is  relevant code in **index.js** file

```
    import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

    render((
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
      </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('app'))
```

`npm start` outputs *webpack: Compiled successfully.*

but in broswer page opens with some random junk in URL *http://localhost:8080/#/?_k=hrfoj1* and display nothing on browser

after searching the issue, came with other [solution suggested](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/8ef625e8fa7c41dda0f3d1d68a10b74bd93a4101/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#what-is-that-_kckuvup-junk-in-the-url) that React Router is built on history.

so tried this

```
    import { Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'

    import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
    const appHistory = createBrowserHistory()

    render((<Router history={appHistory} > ...</Router>),  document.getElementById('app'));
```

but when run `npm start`  gives the error

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module
>   'history/lib/createBrowserHistory' in
>   /opt/react-router-tutorial/lessons/01-setting-up

so Please tell me what is the right solution

Comment: It seems that the tutorial you are following is outdated you might want to follow the examples in the [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web). The package is now called react-router-dom btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is outdated. Basically, there are various types of router components (BrowserRouter, HashRouter, etc.) and they manage their history by themselves.

That is, if you are using `react-router-dom`. You see, `react-router` is now a core package which is used by both `react-router-dom` and `react-router-native` and you should install one of those (in this case, probably `react-router-dom`).

You can then change your code like this (assuming that the render function is coming from somewhere, presumably react-dom):

```
// notice the different package here
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: when  run `npm install react-router-dom --save-dev` it gives an error in terminal 
as UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.8.1 . although project working fine but do I need to worry about it?

Comment: I have followed the link your provide and now getting this issue. Can you please look into this and help me out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263714/separating-single-authentication-file-into-multiple-files-in-react-now-no-disp

Answer (score 1):

^4.7.2 version of 'history' have changed source route, maybe you can try:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/es/createBrowserHistory';

const appHistory = createBrowserHistory()
```