# separating single authentication file into multiple files in react , now no display of login button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Learning from [react router authentication example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow),  I have split the single file code into separate files but now never seeing the login page.
 even no text for protected page

On landing page, there are 3 links
 - Home
 - Public
 - Protected

but when I click on **Protected** Link URL changes to `/login` but bot displaying any text or login button like in the example

instead getting an error in console

> login Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).  ... login

here is the relevant code

#### PrivateRoute.js

```
  import React from 'react'

  import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

  import { fakeAuth } from './fakeAuth'

  export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props}/>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }}/>
      )
    )}/>
  )
```

#### fakeAuth.js

```
    export const fakeAuth = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      authenticate(cb) {
        console.log('is authenticated');
        this.isAuthenticated = true
        setTimeout(cb, 100) // fake async
      },
      signout(cb) {
         console.log('signout');
        this.isAuthenticated = false
        setTimeout(cb, 100)
      }
    }
```

#### AuthButton.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { fakeAuth } from './fakeAuth'

    export const AuthButton = withRouter(({ history }) => (
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <p>
          Welcome! <button onClick={() => {
            fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push('/'))
          }}>Sign out</button>
        </p>
      ) : (
        <p>You are not logged in.</p>
      )
    ))
```

#### Login.js

```
  import React from 'react'

  import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

  import { fakeAuth } from './fakeAuth'


  class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { redirectToReferrer: false };
    }

    login() {
      fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
        this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true })
      })
    }

    render() {
      const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } }
      const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state
      console.log("redirectToReferrer", redirectToReferrer);

      if (redirectToReferrer) {
        return (
          <Redirect to={from}/>
        )
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
          <button onClick={this.login}>Log in</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default Login
```

#### index.jsx

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import App from './App'

    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

    import { AuthButton } from './AuthButton'

    import { Login } from './Login'

    import { PrivateRoute } from './PrivateRoute'

    const Public = () => <h3>Public</h3>
    const Protected = () => <h3>Protected</h3>

    ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
        <App />
        <AuthButton />
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/public">Public Page</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link></li>
          </ul>
          <hr/>
          <Route path="/public" component={Public} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected} />
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>,
      document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

#### App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import logo from '../logo.svg';
    import '../App.css';

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

My suspect is the mistake in **Login.js** as this is a class component but could not figure out what am I missing. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are exporting Login as a default export and importing it as a named import. In index.jsx change:

```
import {Login} from './Login'
```

to

```
import Login from './Login'
```

This will still not work as there is a second bug, the `this` inside `login()` in `Login` is not the correct one, this can be solved by binding the function to the correct this in the constructor. In Login.js use this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { redirectToReferrer: false };
  this.login = this.login.bind(this); // Fix |this| inside login()
}
```

Comment: Wow. it works now. what is the difference in `{}` or without `{}` ? Yes the 2nd one error i have corrected myself. Thank you very much

Comment: A named export is imported with the {} syntax using the name with which it was exported (optionally renaming with a `:` or with `as`). A default export is just a named export (with the name `default`) with some special syntax, it also allows to import with the special syntax `import x from 'there'` which is equivalent to `import {default as x} from 'there'`. More info on that [here](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)